# Can BigQuery be considered a general purpose DW?

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

Most of my platform is on Google Cloud and we are pretty satisfied with it. But for now, it seems to me that although `BigQuery (BQ)` could process unimaginable amounts of data, it will only perform properly in terms of price and performance to a narrow range of sceneries. As we are thinking of changing to `Redshift`, I'd like to share my (probably wrong) conclusions to try to avoid misunderstandings.

Here are the pieces and our conclusions for now:

1. We need to `stream` data to `BQ`. Dimensions content may change and the changes must be streamed to BQ.
2. Say that some user changes transactional `record X` to "`steve`", than to "`John`" and then to "`Robert`". The challenge to stream to `BQ`, due to these [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations), is that you must wait at least 30 minutes to DML record X again (although I've had cache error 42 minutes after DML). So we needed to built much more than just queues, as the third DML does not need to wait 30 minutes and the second DML must be ignored.
3. As you can only have `insert/*` operations running concurrently on a table (`delete/delete, delete/update, update/update` not allowed), all non `insert DML` streaming operation must be `serialized`.
4. `DML latency` is a huge problem. To stream an `insert` is ok, it is very easy to `bulk insert` as well, but to stream a `delete` or `update` will cost you half of a second per operation, and it must be `serialized` on table basis. So, if you have a lot of `updates` happening in your system, it is probable that your `queue` will never end.
5. Although this [paper](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/busting-12-myths-about-bigquery) states `BQ` is capable of handle "workloads that are extremely sensitive to query latency", it seems to me that this depends a lot on your use case. To my use case (small `resultset`), `SQL` latency is too high, at leat two seconds for a small query.
6. [Price](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) is unpredictable and to my understanding does not fit to use cases where you expect to run hundreds of small `resultset` queries over not so big `datasets`. You pay for the columns of the data you access on the [scan](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) (but remember, no indexes). If you have a `60KB resultset` on a `120GB dataset`, you will pay for the `120GB` no matter how precise your [filter condition is](https://statsbot.co/blog/bigquery-vs-redshift-pricing/?utm_campaign=bigquery_pricing&utm_medium=post&utm_source=quora) (you can try to avoid with `sharding`, `partition`, `rollup temporary tables` and other techniques, but it will increase your complexity when a very basic set of indexes could do the job).

Off course, the bright side is that `BQ` is complete `serverless`, no infrastructure complexity, no tuning, no indexes, no worries about High Availability and the storage price is fair.

So, as far as I could understand, if you want low latency, if your data change (even few changes), if you use case does not demand you to scan huge amounts of data, you should avoid `BQ`.

Any considerations are welcomed.

[edit]: Small `Resultset` but big `Dataset`. So probably postgree would not be an option for where we want to be.

Comment: same for Redshift... if your data is small you can just try regular Postgres, or look into streaming analytics platforms like Druid

Comment: Can't you build index in Redshift? The problem is that my resultset is small, the dataset tends to be huge.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, some points I've learned on the issues I've mentioned in my original post.

Although I think that what I wrote is correct, the solution to most of the problems I mentioned is not Redshift. You will solve a couple of problems, create a couple of others and will still face most of them.

So, about what I understood about Redshift that led to make the decision to continue with `BQ` (disclosure: I've worked much more with `BQ`)

- `Redshift` DML latency is as bad as `BQ`. Different cause, almost same symptoms. As [this](https://heapanalytics.com/blog/engineering/redshift-pitfalls-avoid) document states, you may store 1 MB for each column you have updated.
- Too much details on the infrastructure side when compared to `BQ`
- The technology seems older to me. [Shared nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared-nothing_architecture) architecture is a well known source of painful administrative [tasks](https://redshiftuser.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/rebalancing-aws-redshift-clusters/) and although it is a very hard problem to solve, `Oracle` has already [solved](http://Oracle%20RAC%20-%20Wikipedia%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_RAC) this problem more than ten years ago. `Google BQ` face the problem in a completely different way, [separating](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bigquery-under-the-hood) the storage tier from the processing layer. As a `postgre` evolution, Redshift retains some of the `DDL` constraint language (like primary keys) that not are only innocuous but it will generate wrong outputs when using `select distinct`, for instance.
- Not natively supporting complex structures like `arrays` is definitively a no go. It seems that with [spectrum](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-spectrum-extends-data-warehousing-out-to-exabytes-no-loading-required/) Redshift can access external data in S3 but this is not what we were looking for.
- Although I haven't deep dive into the topic, streaming data into `Redshift` seemed to me much more complex than with `BQ`.

On the bright side, It will be [cheaper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpaN-PqSczM&t=1317s) if you use your DW more than 20% of the time, which is my case and you will find more BI tools coverage.

If streaming data and DML latency is paramount, or SQL latency on smaller result set is what you need, you will probably be better with  Oracle or other non columnar DW.

Answer (score -1):

***disclaimer***: I work in GCP support, so I’m less familiar with Redshift, which is also worth looking into.

BigQuery is designed mostly for analytics and you will experience some bigger delays for anything that is not streaming or appending.
If latency is a concern for you, you could also look into [BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/), which provides much lower latencies than BigQuery and may fit your [use-case](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) better.

And, as @AlexYes said, if your data is not so big, your best bet could just be plain PostgreSQL.

Edit: If you need a a database that is relational, in GCP there's also [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/), which shares many ideas BigTable but is relational. Even though it is not advertised as such, it has some analytical features. However, it is a lot pricier than BigQuery.

Comment: But BigTable is not relational. The decision tree should have a question after low latency and updates tree, which is "Do you need a relational database?".

Comment: For completeness, I edited my answer to mention Spanner, which is also relational

Comment: One of the main challenges regarding Spanner, besides the price, is that virtually no BI tool on the market supports it. It seems that Google does not have any viable option to modern massive general purpose DW as far as I could understand, unfortunately